# Is there a scripting language I can embed into my Java app on android

Tags: java, android, scripting

I am making a game engine that is targeted for the Android platform using Java and would like to embed a scripting language into it. I have tried Jython, LuaJava, and Groovy but none of the .jars that I include into my project to utilize the languages are working. In result, my game engine fails to run.

I am aware that the Android platform compiles the app into java bytecode and then converts it into Dalvik-compatible .dex format, since Android uses the Dalvik virtual machine. So I am quite sure that, sadly, these scripting languages likely won't work for a java app project on Android.

So my question is, does there exist a scripting language that I can embed into my Java game engine that will work on the Android platform?

Thanks.

Comment: There are two Lua-using game development frameworks for Android (Corona SDK, Moai), so Lua remains an option even if you haven't gotten it working yet.  Vendetta Online can be extended on-device with Lua scripts.  Anyway: do you want a language to develop your app with, or a language for your users to use to extend your app?  'Scripting language' fuzzes over both uses.

Comment: A language for my users to use to extend my app

Answer (score 2):

Use DeeLang

It should work for what you are using it for or at least what it sounds like you are using it for.

ref URL: http://code.google.com/p/deelang/

Comment: Like mikera said .. there are many answers on Stack Overflow that relate to this. Keep browsing if what you find here doesn't suit you.

Comment: Are there complete examples of using DeeLang? I googled but couldn't find anything. I built the jars and docs. The example on this page gives some insight but isn't complete (such as what would the DeeLang syntax look like in that example). http://code.google.com/p/deelang/wiki/UsingDeeLang.

Answer (score 0):

Clojure would be an option - that definitely works on Android, I've even got a [Clojure REPL app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sattvik.clojure_repl&hl=en) going on my HTC as we speak!

You might also find the answers to [Java: Scripting language (macro) to embed into a Java desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143388/java-scripting-language-macro-to-embed-into-a-java-desktop-application) useful.

Comment: ... and how well does it perform?  How much overhead does it add, in all senses?  How long does it take an app using clojure to start up?  How much of a 'clojure' app must be written in Java?  I ask as the answers to these questions used to outright terrible, and even then people would gush about how someone - not them - could make use of 2-second-startup slow-as-molasses Clojure.

Comment: Haven't benchmarked it so no idea. But Clojure in general is now one of the fastest dynamic langauges around on the JVM, generally within a factor of 2-3 of statically typed langauges like Scala or Java: http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/which-programming-languages-are-fastest.php

Comment: Dalvik's not the JVM, and to reasonably answer my questions you need only have ever used Clojure to develop an Android app.  Answers would then include "no, I haven't noticed any unusual startup delay.", "It adds about .5M to the APK size, after ProGuard, but I haven't tried to reduce that.", etc.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's [still terrible](http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Android+Support).  -1.

Answer (score 0):

LuaJava can be used on Android. Precisely I started with [AndroLua](https://github.com/mkottman/AndroLua) which offers a working example.